# The importance of fitness and cancer

Tags: muscle, recovery

I am a thirty year-old living with a brain tumor. I have made it my every effort to keep myself fit. I do this because I understand it to be beneficial for me should I require ongoing surgery in the future. Given my condition whilst on medication, **how important is a focus on fitness?** Am I putting myself under unnecessary strain or should I continue?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is pretty much straight medical advice, and as such is off topic for the site. I would suggest you consult with your primary physician and oncologist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The American Brain Tumor Association has [several articles about exercise](http://www.abta.org/search/?cx=006527048787565188425%3acsb-shk8ck4&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&q=exercise).
They use words like "sensible" and "moderate". They recommend that you check with your healthcare team before beginning an exercise program.  They say that a physical therapist may direct your exercise program, taking into account any specific mobility, strength or balance issues you may have.

Exercise can provide multiple benefits including improving your energy level, mobility, strength, balance, sleep and reduce stress.  And according to a 2008 experimental study, exercise can reduce some of the damage caused by radiation. (See [Livestrong article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/406815-brain-tumors-exercise/).) But as you mention, exercise can also be stressful.  So the key is to get the right balance of exercise for you, and that should be directed by your healthcare team.  Good luck.